# PHP APC doesn't cache mixed php/html files

Tags: php, performance, apc

I seen, through the APC manager, which APC caches only "pure" php files, while files with php and raw html mixed aren't cached. Does a solution exist for this question?

This a example of mixed code:

```
<html>
<p>fgsfsdfs <?php echo "test" ?></p>
</html>
```

Could I resolve, including all raw html in php "echo function"? How would be performance in this case?